# Can't access custom view in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having problem when it comes to accessing the custom view that I made in CodeIgniter. Whenever I want to navigate to a list in which I am making as an app, it gives me a message saying, **404 Page Not Found** even though I included the model I created in the autoload.php in the config folder. Here are some of my code in the list app that I am creating:

Here is my code in my controller called lists.php:

```
<?php 

    class Lists extends CI_Controller{
    // Display a specific list
    public function display_list($list_id){

        //display information about the list
        $data['list_data'] = $this->lists_model->get_list($list_id);

        $data['main_view'] = 'project_views/lists/display_list';

        $this->load->view('project_views/layouts/main', $data);
    }
?>
```

Here is my code in my model called lists_model.php:

```
<?php 

    class Lists_model extends CI_Model{

    public function get_list($list_id){
            $this->db->where('id', $list_id);
            $query = $this->db->get('lists');

            return $query->row();
        }
?>
```

Here is my code in my view called display_list.php

```
<div class="col-xs-9">

    <h3>List Name:<?php echo $list_data->list_name;?></h3>
    <h3>Created by:<?php echo $list_data->list_creator;?></h3>
    <h3>Lists Details:</h3>
    <p class="lists-description">
        <?php echo $list_data->list_details;?>
    </p>

</div>
```

Here is my code in my index.php in my views folder:

```
<h1>Lists made with Takenote</h1>
<p class="bg-success">

    <?php if($this->session->flashdata('list_created')): ?>
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('list_created'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($this->session->flashdata('list_updated')): ?>
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('list-updated'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($this->session->flashdata('list_deleted')): ?>
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('list_deleted'); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</p>

<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h3>Lists</h3></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="list-group">

            <?php foreach($lists as $list): ?>

            <li class="list-group-item">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>project_controllers/lists/create" class="btn btn-success pull-right">
                    Create a List
                </a>
                <h3 align="center">
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>project_contollers/lists/display_list/<?php echo $list->id;?>">
                        <?php echo $list->list_name; ?>
                    </a>            
                </h3>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I even included the model I created in the autoload.php in the config folder:

```
$autoload['model'] = array('project_models/user_model', 'project_models/project_model', 'project_models/tasks_model', 'project_models/lists_model');
```

However, even after doing this, I still get a message saying **404 Page Not Found** when I try to navigate to a specific list:

Comment: please attach snapshot of the error too.

Comment: I already solved I problem. Careless me what keeps me bugging for 30 mins to an hour long is the incorrect spelling of my path. `<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>project_contollers/lists/display_list/<?php echo $list->id;?>">
                        <?php echo $list->list_name; ?>
                    </a> `

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html#wildcards

It may provide you with the details you need.

I believe you need to add a custom route for this application.

Comment: I already answered my own question but also thanks for your answer. It will really help me a lot in learning CodeIgniter.. Appreciate it..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Careless me. After minutes of debugging, I already solved the problem. What I am missing out is a single letter in the path to where I am adding the link in my index.php. Here is the code I am getting stuck at for minutes to an hour:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>project_contollers/lists/display_list/<?php echo $list->id;?>">
   <?php echo $list->list_name; ?>
</a>
```

It should be like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>project_controllers/lists/display_list/<?php echo $list->id;?>">
  <?php echo $list->list_name; ?>
</a>
```